# generating set for finite fields

Tags: vector-spaces, finite-fields

let us consider GF(2^n) as a vector space over GF(2), Is it possible to find a generating set for GF(2^n)? How can ew find it? I want to define a linear transformation of GF(2^n) to itsefl.

Comment: You mean a generating set as a vectorspace? Pick an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over $GF(2)$, use this to construct $GF(2^n)$ and note that $\{1,x,\dots,x^{n-1}\}$ is a basis.

Comment: As a vector space, it's just the set of $n$-tuples with entries from the field of order 2, and a basis is given by the $n$-tuples with a single 1, all other entries zero.

Comment: So, if we let φ frobenius map for GF(4) over GF(2), then we have :   φ(1)=1 and φ(x)=1+x , φ^2(1)=1 and φ^2(x)=x. and the entries of matrix of frobenius map respectively are : (1,0) and (1,1) as the first and second row of a 2*2 matrix and also (1,0) ,(0,1) as the entries of identity matrix. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For variety, a different approach to defining $GF(2)$-linear endomorphisms of the field $GF(2^n)$ is to observe that the ring of all such endomorphisms is generated by $GF(2^n)$ (which acts by multiplication) and the Frobenius endomorphism $x \mapsto x^2$.